# How to repeat numpy array at specific index changing every loop

Tags: python

I Want to repeat first four indices 1 time, then the next 4 indices but want this dynamic as index number might be changed expected output should be y=[1,1,3,3,1,1,3,3,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]. I am trying to repeat array at specific index as shown in the following code:

```py
import numpy as np
x=np.array([1,1,3,3,5,5,5,5])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
z = np.copy(x)    
for i in range(0, len(x), 4):
       z = np.insert(z, i+4 , x[i:i+4])
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, however, it generates:
[1 1 3 3 1 1 3 3 1 1 3 3 5 5 5 5]
however, expected output should be:
[1 1 3 3 1 1 3 3 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5]

Comment: edited, now it is working